# How can I bind a variable to sequelize literal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have this subquery that is used to check the existence of a column related to the source model.

```
const defaultingLoans = await Loan.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.and]: database.sequelize.literal('EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "Instalments" WHERE "Instalments"."loanId" = "Loan"."id" AND "Instalments"."status" = 'pending')')
    }
  });
```

The query works fine but the value `pending` ideally won't be fixed so I'll like to have a variable there that can be used to query for different status.

How can I replace the pending string with a variable.

Concatenation didn't work here because Sequelize has a weird way of parsing concatenated SQL queries which result in an error. An example is here https://pastebin.com/u8tr4Xbt and I took a screenshot of the error [here](https://imagebin.ca/v/4RbsQOAPaxvO)

Comment: Are you familiar with concatenating variables to strings?

Comment: @Hydrothermal String concatenation doesn't work with sequelize literal

Comment: What makes you say that?  `literal()` is being given a string as an argument.  It doesn't matter how it's constructed.  Just that it is a valid string.  `literal('abc')` and `literal('ab'+ 'c')` would both pass the same string to the method

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the way sequelize parses concatenated SQL strings, take a look at the query: https://pastebin.com/u8tr4Xbt

The image is the error gotten when I run that: https://imagebin.ca/v/4RbsQOAPaxvO

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can turn `defaultingLoans` into a function which accepts an amount:

```
const defaultingLoans = amount => await Loan.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.and]: database.sequelize.literal(`EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "Instalments" WHERE "Instalments"."loanId" = "Loan"."id" AND "Instalments"."amount" = ${amount})`)
  }
});
```

usage:

```
const loans = defaultingLoans(2000);
```

**EDIT**: Although it should be noted here that you need to sanitize or quote the `amount` getting passed into this function to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the way sequelize parses concatenated SQL strings, take a look at the query: pastebin.com/u8tr4Xbt The image is the error gotten when I run that: imagebin.ca/v/4RbsQOAPaxvO

Comment: That's because `clause1` and `clause2` are strings - you need to include quotes around the concatenated values when using strings

Comment: Something like this 

    database.sequelize.literal(`EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "Instalments" WHERE "Instalments"."loanId" = "Loan"."id" AND "Instalments"."status" IN ("${clause1}", "${clause2}"))`)

yeah? Still gives me the same error.

Comment: If not, can you help share a sample of what you're talking about, thanks.

Comment: I believe sequelize requires single quotes for strings, so try `('${clause1}', '${clause2}')`

Comment: This isn't exactly binding. It'll concatenate the param to the query string.

Comment: Be careful with SQL Injection in this cases if this is exposed to users. Amount could be `'2000; DELETE FROM "Instalments";'`

Answer (score 4):

You can put your `bind` object right inside your query object:

```
let status = 'Pending';
const defaultingLoans = await Loan.findAll({
    where: database.sequelize.literal('EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "Instalments" WHERE "Instalments"."loanId" = "Loan"."id" AND "Instalments"."status" = $status)'),
    bind: {status}
});
```